# C# passing dynamic method as parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates

So I have a dynamic object and I want to execute a method from it but I need the method to be passed in as a parameter. I have found no way to do this and was wondering if anyone here could help.

something like:

```
public static void RunMethod(methodInTheDynamicObject)
{
    myDynamicObject.methodInTheDynamicObject();
}
```

Comment: myDynamic as in the `dynamic` keyword in C# 4 or dynamic as in dynamically compiled?

Comment: How is it backed? Do you have ability to inquire on its properties in its current form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably should have let you know that my dynamic object was an Iron-Python script. Anyways I figured out.

```
public static void RunMethod(string script, string method, object[] param)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic dynamicObj = Scripts[script];
        var operations = ironPython.Operations;
        operations.InvokeMember(dynamicObj, method, param);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My preference in this case is usually to define a delegate:

```
public delegate void MyFunction(string p1, int p2);

public void Foo(MyFunction myFunction) {
    myFunction("something", 2);
}
```

Or you can use System.Reflection and pass in MethodInfo and use it like so:

```
public void Foo(MethodInfo methodInfo) {
    methodInfo.Invoke(new object[] {"something", 2});
}
```

You can find out more about MethodInfo.Invoke [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx). They have some examples. But again, delegates are probably the cleaner way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are wanting to pass in a delegate. See the example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/joycsharp/archive/2008/02/15/simple-c-delegate-sample.aspx

If you needed a hardcore approach for runtime generated methods you could try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx